# How to add 3rd party/local framework along with flutter dependencies together in same flutter project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, flutter, sdk

I am working on flutter project where i need to integrate my flutter code with native objective c framework(local framework).

when i am not using any flutter dependencies then its working fine but when i add any flutter dependencies e.g path_provider or image_cropper etc at that time app is showing error i.e.

> 1./Users//Desktop///ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: 'image_cropper/ImageCropperPlugin.h' file not found.

What i think is that this issue is because of podfile configuration because:

1. when i have not used "use_frameworks!" this in pod file then all dependencies which i have used in flutter can be seen in .a format(static library) along with my local framework/sdk but when i used "use_frameworks!" statement in pod all libraries along with my local SDK(framework) is coming in .framework format.
2. i want flutter libraries/dependencies to come in .a format and my framework to come in .framework format.

podfile that i am using:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def applibs
  pod 'ThirdPartySDK-Debug', :configuration => ['Debug'], :path  => 'Generated_Key_IOS_SDK/Debug/ThirdPartySDK-Debug.podspec'
  pod 'ThirdPartySDK-Release', :configuration => ['Release'], :path  => 'Generated_Key_IOS_SDK/Release/ThirdPartySDK-Release.podspec'
end

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  workspace 'Runner.xcworkspace'
  project 'Runner.xcodeproj'
  applibs
  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Runner.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Runner.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

i want flutter libraries/dependencies to come in .a format and my framework to come in .framework format.

Comment: Did you find a solution?